# question about changing order of series and convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

"if  $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\left(a_n\right)$ converge  to $S$ and it non-negative series, so every other series that we get by change the order of the items in the original series, also converge to that $S$"

I want to prove this statement. But i hardly know how to start, so i wrote this so far:
Let:
$S_k\:=\:a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5+a_6+.....+a_k$
$T_k\:=\:a_{\sigma 1}+a_{\sigma 2}+a_{\sigma 3}+a_{\sigma 4}+a_{\sigma 5}+a_{\sigma 6}+...+a_{\sigma k}$

be the partial sums of the original series and the "new" series, respectively.
I want to use squeeze theorem to bounded $T_k$ but i cant figure out how. any ideas for another way of proof? tnx!

Comment: As the series is convergent and all the terms are non-negative, it is also absolutely convergent.

Comment: @James so what it tells me?

Comment: Absolutely convergent sequences satisfy the conclusion of the theorem you are trying to prove: You can re-arrange the series and the limit is preserved. A proof is here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolutely_convergent#Rearrangements_and_unconditional_convergence (although this is more general than you need).

Answer (score 0):

It suffices to show that $ T_k \geq S - \epsilon$ for any epsilon since then we can apply $\sigma ^{-1}$ to $T$ and get the reverse inequality.

Take $N$ such that $ \sum _{n\geq N} a_n \leq \epsilon$ then we have 
$S_N=\sum _{n\leq N}a_n \geq S- \epsilon $. We take $ M$ such that $T_M$ contains all of the terms appearing in $S_N$ then this implies that $ T_m \geq S-\epsilon$.